# coldfusion ajax jquery file-upload not working

Tags: jquery, file-upload, coldfusion

Here's my situation. I have a photo administration page which includes 1) a photo upload template 2) a photo details template 3) a featured photo template 4) a photo gallery and 5) a dynamic nav bar. Originally, the photo upload template was set up as a form which submitted to itself and which used cffile to upload the new photo. This worked well until I tried to add jquery callbacks to refresh the details, featured photo, and gallery containers on successful upload - but I find that after the form is submitted and the photo is uploaded, any other functions that I attach to the form's submit button don't run.

Because of that, I decided to change the submit button to be type "button" and use jquery .ajax() to upload the file, so I could add my callbacks on success. My code for the ajax method so far is:

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'Administration/PhotoManagement/uploadPhotos.cfm',
            type: 'POST',           
            data: { Add: 'add',
                NewFilename: file_name,
                shortName: short_name,
                description: description
            },
            contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
            success: function(response, status, xhr){
                    $('#upload').html(response);
                    // refresh gallery, featured pic, details
                    alert('success');
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr, status){
                alert(status + ' ' + xhr.statusText);
            }           
        });
```

On submit, I get 500 internal server error. Firebug console reports that the data got posted correctly, but the image doesn't get uploaded and I don't get an error message from the try/catch error code that I have around the cffile.

I'm not married to either approach - I'd be fine with going back to the original approach if I could get the callbacks to work. Any suggestions? If you think I should stay with the ajax approach, what would you recommend I try to fix my errors?

Edit: in the code above, I had added type:multipart/form data because I had been getting an error from my try/catch block around the  tag:

> Invalid content type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8

Comment: What are the details for the 500 error? Use firebug or some proxy (Charles) to get the details.

Comment: have you tried using jQuery ajax file upload plugins?

Comment: Lucas, am unable to use proxies here at work. Firebug won't give me the details of the 500 error; it shows a ? after localhost. Removing "type: multipart/form-data" makes that error go away, but my cffile tag then gives me the "invalid content type" error listed above.

Comment: tsurahman, is there one that you recommend?

Comment: I was under the impression you could not do file uploads via an AJAX request.

Comment: yeah, that's what I'm starting to understand... bah humbug.

Comment: @user724075, in these scenarios, I usually have the file upload form in an iFrame, and work across the iframe to pull in whether uploads were successful or not. There are security issues with pushing files through AJAX requests. Your best bet is to fall back to an iframe, or potentially to a flash-based uploader that can then run callbacks after handling the upload through the flash player. I've used http://www.uploadify.com/ for this to good effect. http://www.plupload.com/ also looks good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a little late to the party, but I've used this before as an AJAX fileuploader using coldfusion:

http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

When you download the package there is an example using coldfusion.

In the javascript file, there is a function that has a callback method called 'onComplete' (Search for `qq.FileUploaderBasic`).  In that callback method call your own callback function like this:

```
onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON)
    {
        uploaderCallBackFunction(id, fileName, responseJSON);
    },
```

Where `uploaderCallBackFunction` is a function I wrote.  You can pass JSON from the CFC to the callback function if you would like too.

Comment: Hey the link seems to be dead on this one. Do you have another copy?

Comment: @Will I unfortunately don't have a copy, but I would recommend a more modern plugin that I've used successfully (not with CF though): https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Comment: Yeah I have been looking into making a server side for CF for that. Seems to be the best option. Thanks anyway.